# Is it possible to define your own bootstrap class inside your own class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I thought i would find this quite easily.
Is it possible to define a bootstrap css class inside your own class?

## Example

```
.myclass {
    .bootstrapclass,
    .anotherbootstrapclass
}
```

## More specific bootstrap example

```
.twocollayout {
    .col-xs-6,
    .col-md-6,
    .col-lg-4
}
```

Comment: i think u have to use less

Comment: Less? Less what? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two part answer:

(1) Can you include another CSS class?

- If you're using LESS version then maybe: if there is a mixin for it.  See [Less Mixins](http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-mixins)
- If you're using the SCSS version then yes.  See [The Extend Concept](https://css-tricks.com/the-extend-concept/) *(mind you, [some say](https://www.sitepoint.com/avoid-sass-extend/) not to)*

(2) .col-xs-6, .col-lg-4

- No!  BS `.col-x-x` classes don't work like that. They are tied to [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).  As the media query is the outer define for the .col-'s any attempt to mixin will revert to the non-m/query version.  technically it will work but your end class will just be a set of `width: xx%;` calls, one after another - thus only the last one true.

Answer (score 0):

These are some of the better tutorial I could find about Bootstrap 3 Less Workflow.

http://www.helloerik.com/bootstrap-3-less-workflow-tutorial

http://bootstrap.lesscss.ru/less.html

And if you want to learn Less, you can refer these links

http://lesscss.org (the official less website)

http://groupdocs.com/blog/using-bootstrap-with-less-css-tutorial

http://designshack.net/articles/css/using-less-js-to-simplify-your-css3

Regards!!!